# Resizable stops working when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrollable div and made it resizable at the bottom:

```
$("#mydiv").resizable({
  handles: "s",
});
```

It works, but only if it is fully scrolled to the top:

[image]

When you scroll it down, the resizable function seems to stop working:

[image]

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bmg7v7y/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a play with it and found a solution(hopefully). I placed your `.resizable()` in a container div as follows and everything seems to be working in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BFG/sa3jx440/5/). The code:

HTML:

```
<div id="resizeContainer">

  <div id="mydiv" class="ui-widget-content">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-icons-front-views/480/Sports_Car_Front_View-512.png" width="400">
  </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#resizeContainer").resizable({
  handles: "s",
});
```

CSS:

```
#resizeContainer { 
  height: 200px; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  padding-right: 20px; 
}  

#mydiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  padding: 0.5em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this fixes it:

```
$("#mydiv").on("resize", function(){
    $("#mydiv").resizable({
        handles: "s",
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it? The inner part needs to be called, in order to work. But it will never be. Resizeception...

Comment: It did work for me! It is not very elegant, though. Doesn't it work for you ?

Comment: The inner part is what makes the div resizable. But it will only be executed, when the div will be resized. So it can't work. Or do you mean actually **adding** it to the already existing code?